# how do I save my database tables and values?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller, publish

I have an asp.net mvc website, and I would like to know if/how to save my database tables and values to my migrations/models so when I publish my website the first time it runs it creates the database on the iis sql server and fills the tables with the data? I am using sql server 2016 on my computer and on the server. right now it creates a default database on first run but no tables get created. I have just been making the database and tables manually when I publish, but I want to know if its possible to have it done automatically.

Comment: If you have an SSDT project, you can add a custom post-deploy script that will `INSERT` any initial data that you need.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @Dai I looked into that and noticed it says for visual studios 2015 I am using 2017 so I don't think that will work. oh nevermind I found a 2017 version I will try this thank you!

Comment: @AWinkle yes I am using Entity Framework

Comment: If you add `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TConfiguration>());` to your `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax.cs` it will automatically apply your migrations (assuming you are using code first) to the database when the app starts.

Comment: @AWinkle my migrations folder has initialcreate.cs and nothing else, but I have no idea what that does. im really new at this.. I have 2 databases one is for the login storage and one is for everything else (news, events, and profiles) that I can edit on the website. do I have to create migrations for both databases? thanks for the help!

Comment: I recommend using this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) first, and then seeing where you are. And yes, you must create one context per database.